# How To Solve This Trying to get property of non-object Error In Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm creating a web site. And I have created a registration page. I want to update my details.

But, It gives me this error and I have also uploaded a picture of errors below. - 
[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA5Q9.png)

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   D:\wamp64\www\FinalProject\resources\views\AdminUpdate.blade.php)

I used dd($edd); and it gave me correct details. But, when I try with below codes it gives me that above error.

How can I Fix this ??

Here is my AdminPanel.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

<tr>
<td> Name </td>
</tr>


@foreach($data as $value )
<tr>
<td> {{ $value->username }} </td>
<td> <a href="edit/{{ $value->id }}"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" class="btn-primary"></a> </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

Here is my AdminPanelController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
$edd = User::find($id);
//dd($edd);
      return view('AdminUpdate', ['edd' => $edd]);

}

    public function adminedit($id, Request $request, User $user)
{
    // Add Validation

    $users = $user->find($id);
    $users->username = $request->get('username');
    $users->email = $request->get('email');
    $users->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Here is my AdminUpdate.blade.php

```
<form action="edit/{{ $edd[0]->id }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{$edd[0]->username}}" placeholder="Enter Your Username" required>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email : *</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$edd[0]->email}}" placeholder="Enter Your Username" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password : *</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{$edd[0]->password}}" placeholder="Enter Your Password" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Upload Profile Picture :</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file_img" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">If U Want , U Can Skip Upload A Profile Picture</small>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update User">
                    </form>
```

Here are my Routes.

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'AdminPanelController@edit');

Route::post('/edit/{id}', 'AdminPanelController@adminedit');
```

Comment: It tells you that the user wasn't found, but if you output `$edd` and post it here it may be possible to say exactly why this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't write `{{ $edd[0]->id }}` instead of this use:

```
{{ $edd->id }}
```

Comment: Thank U Very Much !! It Worked !!

Answer (score 4):

`User::find()` gives you a single **object**, not array.

So, in blade just use

```
$edd->id
```

Same applies to other instances of `$edd`: username, email, password.

As a sidenote: you can add a check if user is really found by `id` and if not - show 404 page, for example.

Comment: Thank U Very Much !! It Worked !!

Answer (score 2):

Change { $edd[0]->id }} line to

{{ $edd->id }}